# How can you stop IE 11/Edge from showing the autocomplete list when you click an input?

Tags: html, input, autocomplete, dropdown

So I have a simple autocomplete input

```
<input type="search" list="suggestions" placeholder="Search for something..">
<datalist id="suggestions">
    <option value="option 1" />
    <option value="option 2" />
    <option value="option 3" />
</datalist>
```

In Chrome/Firefox, once the user clicks the input and starts typing, suggestions will appear, everything works as expected. In IE, as soon as the user clicks the input the whole dropdown is displayed, making it very user-unfriendly. How can I disable the dropdown from appearing on the click event of the input and only get it to appear once the user has actually typed something?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_autocomplete .. Check this..